# UIWebView to View Controller?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I was wondering if anyone knew if this was possible?

I have a uiwebview as the first view controller which is showing a basic html page I made with the Facebook login screen. Can you login (in the uiwebview) and once it authorises you (in the uiwebview) it closes and launches the second view controller?

Does anyone know of a good example or tutorial for this?

If not can someone point me in the direction of a good FacebookSDK example or tutorial in Storyboard not XIB?

Thanks!

Comment: Is there an specific problem you are facing? Do you wish to use the UIWebView or the Facebook SDK? For your tutorial needs, I'll recommend that the official documentation is the best. Both from Apple and Facebook.

Comment: I would prefer the Facebook SDK, I can't seem to find information for Storyboard though, I have built my app in Storyboard and want to add the login option to it... I've checked official documentation and can't find anything for Storyboard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Download the Facebook sdk from [github](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk) and check the SessionLoginSample in samples. I think it has everything you need

Answer (score 3):

You should be using the  `FBLoginView`  and  `FBSession`  classes of the Facebook SDK to log in. You can just use the delegate callbacks from those to drive your next view controller.

I can't think of a reason you would want to bring up the facebook login page in a  `UIWebView` , rather than doing the above. If for some reason you actually need to use a  `UIWebView` , the  `webViewDidFinishLoad:`  method of  `UIWebViewDelegate`  might provide you with the hook you need.